# Infix To Postfix conversion in Assembly Language Using MASM (for x86 processor)

Tags: assembly, masm

I am pretty much stuck now in this problem, i have task that requires **Infix to Post**-fix conversion.When i execute code it asks me for the input after that if i give it more than 2 values of numbers it stops working and if i type 2 values with different expression it removes the last number i.e (3+5-3 OR 4/2+5). I am a **Beginner** Please Help Guys

**This is my Code below :-**

```
INCLUDE C:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

INCLUDE C:\Irvine\macros.inc

CheckAddSub PROTO, seStr1:PTR BYTE, outStr1:PTR BYTE, pCo:DWORD, pDo:DWORD, 

outCo1:DWORD

CheckMulDiv PROTO, seStr2:PTR BYTE, outStr2:PTR BYTE, theCo:DWORD, 
theDo:DWORD, outCo2:DWORD

.data

inputStr BYTE 20 dup(?)    ;input array

outputStr BYTE 20 dup(?)   ;postfix array

sizeSt DWORD 20

secStr BYTE 10 dup(?)    ;to store the operator

count DWORD 0

dStr DWORD 0

outCount DWORD 0

.code

main PROC

    mWrite "Input: "

    mov edx, OFFSET inputStr 

    mov ecx, SIZEOF inputStr - 1

   call ReadString

mov esi, OFFSET inputStr     ;now the input str has elements

mov edi, OFFSET outputStr    ;for storing the postfix 

mov ecx, eax                 ;to loop

L1:

    mov ebx, [esi]
    .if bl=='+'|| bl=='-' 
        inc count             

    .if count > 1           ;when count is 2 mean there is already element in 
                           ;  the secStr array so i can do the checking
        INVOKE CheckAddSub, ADDR secStr, ADDR outputStr, count, dStr,outCount
        inc dStr        ;dStr is to store the index number of the secStr 
                        ; array, after the zero index predencency is checked, 
                        ;increment dStr to indicate the index number this 
                       ;  current operator in secStr array

    .endif

    mov [edx],ebx     ;put the operator into secStr

  add edx,1

    .elseif bl=='*'|| bl =='/'

      inc count

    .if count > 1

      INVOKE CheckMulDiv, ADDR secStr, ADDR outputStr , count, dStr, outCount

      inc dStr

  .endif

    mov [edx],ebx   

  add edx,1

    .else                  ;when it is operand(number), put into output array

     mov [edi], ebx

     inc outCount

  .endif

    inc edi

  inc esi

  dec ecx  

  cmp ecx,0

  jne L1    

    mov edx, OFFSET outputStr

  mWrite "the postfix string is: "

  call WriteString

   INVOKE ExitProcess,0

 main ENDP
 ;-----------------------------------------------------------
 CheckAddSub PROC USES edx edi eax ecx ebx,

seStr1:PTR BYTE,      ;secStr

 outStr1:PTR BYTE,     ;outputStr

 pCo:DWORD, 

 pDo:DWORD,

 outCo1:DWORD
;------------------------------------------------------------

    mov edx, seStr1      

    mov edi, outStr1

LW:
    mov ebx, [edx+pDo]            ;edx+pDo is the last element in the array, 
                                    ; like stack the top element

    .if bl=='+'|| bl=='-'|| bl=='*' || bl=='/'

         mov [edi+outCo1],ebx      ;if one of these operator exists in the 

                                    ;secStr array, then put this operator into 
                                    ;the outputStr array 

         mov [edx+pDo], 0          ;put null in this current index,indicating 

                                   ; this element is already pop out from the 
                                    ;secStr array    

         inc outCo1 

    .endif

    .if pDo!=0

         sub pDo,1

    .endif

    dec pCo         

    cmp pCo,1

    jne LW

    je L5

L5: ret 

CheckAddSub ENDP

;------------------------------------------------------
CheckMulDiv PROC USES edx edi eax ecx ebx,

  seStr2:PTR BYTE, 

  outStr2:PTR BYTE, 

  theCo:DWORD, 

  theDo:DWORD,

  outCo2:DWORD
;-------------------------------------------------------

   mov edx, seStr2

   mov edi, outStr2

LR:

   mov ebx,[edx+theDo]

   .if bl=='*'|| bl=='/'

      mov [edi+outCo2],ebx

      mov [edx+theDo],0

      inc outCo2

   .endif

   .if theDo!=0

     sub theDo,1

   .endif

   dec theCo

   cmp theCo, 1

   jne LR

   je L6

L6: ret

CheckMulDiv ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Do you have a working C version?

Comment: No Sir..This is the only code i have